# Compare Object and Boolean has different results using `!=` and `==`

Tags: javascript, equality

I'm having trouble understanding the behaviour of the equality operator in JavaScript. This is what I get when I run the following commands on a browser's console:

```
new Object() == true  // returns false
new Object() != false // returns true
```

Now, I don't agree with the fact that an Object should be false (although I have understood *why* after checked the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)), but what really bothers me is that I get two different results on two equivalent logical expressions.

What's happening?

Comment: `What's happening?` You're using sloppy equality. Use strict equality instead and things will be much more predictable. (also note that objects are never equal to anything except themselves, loose or strict)

Comment: Its not strict equality and yes Object is not false but its not true either, if you use a boolean constructor , this should behave correctly

Comment: `!=` checks the value. For exapmle `'5' != 5` will return false.

Comment: But when the documentation says that `0`, `-0`, `null`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined`, or the empty string are evaluated to `false` and everything else is `true`, shouldn't that include Objects too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec, both of these should return `false` (this aligns with common sense to me):

```
new Object() == true  // false
new Object() == false // false
```

based on:

> 9. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>      return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 10. Return false.

Since they both return false and:

> A != B is equivalent to !(A == B).

both of these should be `true`:

```
new Object() != true  // true
new Object() != false // true
```

*note:*
This shouldn't be confused with the *truthiness* of `new Object()`. In other words `new Object() == true` is not the same `Boolean(new Object()) == true`

Comment: I get your point, but can you expand a bit your last note? Why aren't those two statement the same? Shouldn't `new Object` be automatically casted to `Boolean`?

Comment: @Cynical the spec says nothing about casting when the left hand is an object and the right hand is not a String or Number. So it shouldn't be cast —  it should just return false. Casting an object to boolean does happen in other contexts however like in an [`if` condition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) where you're not testing equality but whether the object is *truthy*.

Answer (score 1):

You linked to [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) which gives a 10 step list of things to check based on what the left and right-hand sides are.

The left-hand side is an object. The right-hand side is a boolean.

This means that it hits step 10:

> Return false.

An object is not equal to `true` nor is it equal to `false`.

Comment: So what you mean is that an Object is neither `true` nor `false`, but as Mark Meyer said in another answer, its Boolean conversion is always `true`?

Comment: @Cynical — Comparing to true or false is not the same as passing it as an argument to the Boolean constructor function.